# Beaglebone black not working

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, beagleboard, hardware-interface

I bought beaglebone black 2 months back and it was working fine for one month after then I got busy in some work and didn't use it for a month and now when I try to connect it with my computer its not detected, not even when I do dmesg

Does anyone have any idea how to fix that? I researched on Google and some people are saying beaglebone's connector is loose but I am not that hardware guy who can fix it plus I can't afford to buy new beaglebone because I am a student.

Comment: does your board blink when connected? Have you tried to connect your board with another system?

Comment: Yes it does, and yes I tried it on all system

Comment: Unplug the Arduino, then uninstall the the Arduino software. Then restart. Plug in the arduino. The computer should recognize it and install the appropriate drivers.

Comment: Do try with different IDE.

Comment: 1) Connect a micro-HDMI cable to the monitor and see what happens. 
2) Connect a serial-console cable and see what it reports. You will need to make such cable yourself and add an UART-USB adapter (or use one [off-the-shelf solution](http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBone_Black_Serial))

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem: my BeagleBone worked fine and then a month later it wouldn't connect to my Mac. (I'm assuming that you're using a Mac since you mention dmesg.)

The issues I encountered:

1. I had to turn off Sharing > Internet Sharing to connect via USB networking (even though the documentation says to turn on Internet Sharing).
2. I needed to reinstall the rel8pre2 version (specifically) of the HoRNDIS driver for USB networking to work.
3. Ethernet wouldn't work because my router had wedged and wouldn't give a DHCP lease. Rebooting the router fixed this.
4. Since I had installed VPN on my Mac, I needed to turn off VPN to connect to the BeagleBone via Ethernet.
5. FTDI serial is very flaky for me. 2/3 of the time I get garbage characters (like it's out of sync or has the wrong baud rate). After trying to connect multiple times it will suddenly start working right. Also, I can only plug the USB cable in once; the second time no /dev/tty.usbserial device shows up. Rebooting the Mac fixes this. (Anyone have a fix for the serial line problems?)

Hopefully one of these will solve your problem. Overall, using a Mac with the BeagleBone seems much more flaky than using it with Windows. Maybe try connecting to a Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

If it is still blinking then it must be working.

Try to use reset button, or put a pin on P9_7. It works for me a few times.